# Understanding how variables are passed

Tags: javascript, variables, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I just can't understand how variables are passed, why are some passed by reference while other by value?

**Example:**

```
var a=4;
var b=a;
b=b++;
alert(a);//unmodified 4

var c=["t","ttt"];
var d=c;
d=d.sort(function(x,y){return (y.length-x.length);});
alert(c);//modified ["ttt","t"]
```

Where can I find a list of what variables will work like the first example and which like the second? (booleans, strings, etc... there are too many to test them all by miself)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript is *always* pass by value.

It's very common to say that objects in JavaScript are pass by reference, however that is not true. In a true pass by reference language, you could pass a reference to an object's reference, and have it point to another object. This is not possible in JavaScript.

Take, for example, C#. By default everything in C# is pass by value, just like JavaScript.

```
void foo(string s) {
    s = "passbyvalue";
}

string a = "original value";
foo(a);
// a is still "original value"
```

However, if you alter `foo` to use pass by reference, the behavior changes:

```
void foo(ref string s) {
    s = "passbyreference";
}
string a = "original value";
foo(ref a);
// a is now "passbyreference"
```

In JavaScript, only the first example is possible.

In JavaScript, everything is pass by value. This includes the object reference (yes, it is confusing). The reference itself is a value (it's very much like a pointer). It merely contains an id that allows the runtime to look up the object that is most likely stored in its heap. When you pass an object to a function, you are *actually copying its reference into the function*

It may be a seemingly small, and even anal, difference. But it's a key difference. Languages that have true pass by reference such as C# and C++ allow you to do things that are simply not possible in languages like JavaScript. The above trite example is one.

Comment: what does "a*al" mean in your context? I would usually google that, but I really don't want to

Answer (score 3):

Imagine everything in JavaScript as an object. Object references are copied by value, but object properties are still used by reference. So:

```
var a = {};
var b = a;
b = 'Blah';
console.log(a); // Still {}
```

and

```
var a = {};
var b = a;
b.test = 'Blah';
console.log(a); // Is now {test: 'Blah'}
```

To simplify things a little: properties are by reference, values are by value.

Comment: +1 I think this ans can finally make me understand it! I will read this like 4-5 times until it somehow gets into my brain

Answer (score 1):

All objects get passed by reference and values by value. (technically this is not true, but it explains the behaviour)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can check the method on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference). For example, the [`sort` method's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) states (emphasis added):

> Sorts the elements of an array **in place** and returns the array.

The "in place" there says it will modify the array.

All primitives (for example, numbers and booleans) are passed by value; all objects are passed by reference, although some (like `String` objects) are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) (although still passed by reference).

Comment: it just had that in place issue one question ago. it would have been better if I asked this question first, so I would never had asked my previous one)